# Auto login after registration confirmation

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am using the JavaScript SDK of AWS Cognito (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html).

When a new user completes registration confirmation, the documentation says the user is now ready to sign in.  Is it possible to automatically sign in the user at this time?

For e.g., after confirmation when I use the following I get null:

```
userPool.getCurrentUser();
```

If this is the intended behavior, are there any ways to sign in the user without explicitly asking the user again?

I know this is not a good idea, one thing I can think of is to save the user credentials in local storage and use them after confirmation to automatically sign in. Any other ideas better than this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon user signup, your backend will be receiving users credentials, which you can use to generate the JWT token. Then you can add the JWT token in the same response, which can be use by the browser client to request authorized endpoints.

Example:

```js
     AWSCognito.config.region = 'us-east-1'; //This is required to derive the endpoint
    
     var poolData = {
         UserPoolId: 'us-east-1_TcoKGbf7n',
         ClientId: '4pe2usejqcdmhi0a25jp4b5sh3'
     };
     var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
     var attributeList = [];
     var dataEmail = {
         Name: 'email',
         Value: 'email@mydomain.com'
     };
     var authenticationData = {
         Username: 'username',
         Password: 'password',
     };
     var attributeEmail = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(dataEmail);
     attributeList.push(attributeEmail);
    
     userPool.signUp(authenticationData.Username, authenticationData.Password, attributeList, null, function (err, result) {
         if (err) {
             alert(err);
             return;
         }
         var authenticationDetails = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
         var userData = {
             Username: authenticationData.Username,
             Pool: userPool
         };
         var cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);
         cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
             onSuccess: function (result) {
                 console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
                 /*Use the idToken for Logins Map when Federating User Pools with Cognito Identity or when passing through an Authorization Header to an API Gateway Authorizer*/
                 console.log('idToken + ' + result.idToken.jwtToken);
                 /*Return the result.idToken.jwtToken with the response*/
             },
             onFailure: function (err) {
                 alert(err);
             },
    
         });
     });
```

Comment: this is all server side code right ? i.e. it is all wrapped in an api that a client is calling ?

Comment: Looks like browser code to me. Also looks like it doesn't handle there being an email confirm step in the middle, which complicates things as the user is likely to close the window.

Comment: @Crazometer You can run the code serverside with NodeJS

Comment: @Ashan while it is possible to run on node it probably isn't advisable. Using cognito you would never expect the backend to know the `{username, password}` pairs.

Comment: @Crazometer Agree on most of the cases. However, we might need it to transparently move the users from a legacy login where the hashed password and username is stored in a DB (To check the match succeeds and if so to create one in Cognito). Of cause, we can ask the user to change it soon after the first login.